# .htaccess for my API system

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Which allows me make calls like `mywebsite.com/api/addComment` and redirect it to `mywebsite.com/api/api.php?rquest=addComment`.

Now I'm trying to extend it and make it more efficient, but I can't figure it how. I would like to make different calls to specific files, like this:

`/api/comments/add` redirected to `/api/comments.php?request=add`

`/api/users/delete` redirected to `/api/users.php?request=delete`

...and so on. I suppose there bust me some sort of conditions in the htaccess. Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/api/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1.php?rquest=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,L]
```